# PHP: submitted form won't be shown again

Tags: php

I'm trying to use Sessions in PHP and I'm trying to make a form which when was submitted in past will not be shown again to the same user.

Now my script only prefill inputs is there any option to do it as I said?

**Script:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form id="auth-form" method="POST" action="../_inc/get-access.php">
<input type="mail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
<button type="submit">Získať prístup</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If i should understand you clearly,
1. You have a form?
2. You display the form to user?
3. You want user to be able to fill the form and form.
but after they have submitted the form, they shouldnt be able to fill/submit the same form again?

Comment: Maybe after `session_start();` add `if(!empty($_SESSION["email"])){` assuming you populated that once form is filled. Otherwise use some index you use when form is completed.

Comment: @Homezonic yes I need what you wrote.

Comment: maybe alternative with cookies?

Comment: I dont really know or should i say understand the structure of your code and files, i will suggest on user submitting the form, you should destroy the session and redirect them to successful page. what do you think? @MatúšRebroš

Comment: Sessions does not identify a specific user. It only specifies a specific session in a browser for X minuters.